# How to repair cluster periodically, -local or -pr one by one

Tags: cassandra

I am confused that how to repair the Cassandra cluster.
Below command repairs all nodes of the local datacenter?
`nodetool repair -local -j 4`
So, I needn't run `nodetool repair -pr -j 4` on all nodes one by one?

Answer (score 0):

Running `nodetool repair` on a single node does the following: The node repairs all data that it holds by contacting other nodes which are also responsible for this data. It will **not** repair data which this node is **not** responsible for.

***A very simple example without vnodes is this:***

Consider you have three nodes (A, B and C) and your lowest replication is two. If you run repair on A, it will run repair on data which A and B have in common as well as data which A and C have in common. However it will not repair the data which is only stored on B and C.

In this example, running the repair on two nodes will ensure that you have repaired everything.

***The -pr and -local flags***

The -pr flag changes this behavior even further. Instead of repairing AB and AC. You only repair data which A is primarily responsible for. In this case you need to repair B and C separately. This ensures that you do not repair the same data twice.

-local will ensure that the repair only repairs nodes in the same datacenter. B was in a different datacenter, it will be ignored for the purpose of the repair.

I would recommend to run -pr on each node one by one. This will avoid repairing the same data multiple times and break it down into smaller digestable chunks.

Comment: but as document shows, -local would repair all data in same datacenter.  
So, if A,B,C are in same datacenter, they would be repaired.

Comment: -local only restricts the repair to nodes in the same datacenter. Repair still only repairs the data that the current node holds.